# Does the Bang– Zsigmondy theorem generalizes?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The following statement consists of a classical result of Bang and Zsigmondy as well as its elliptic analog.

Let $K$ be a number field. $A/K$ be an one-dimensional semi-abelian variety,  $P\in A(K)$ be a non-torsion point, and $S$ be a finite set of places of $K$ including all the archimedean ones, all ones of bad reduction for $A$, and every $v$ such that $P\notin A(O_v)$. For each place $v\notin S$, let $\text{ord}_v(P)$ be the order of the image of $P$ in $A({\mathbb F}_v)$, where ${\mathbb F}_v$ is the residue field at $v$. Then the subset $\{\text{ord}_v(P): v\notin S\}$ of the set of natural numbers is cofinite.

My question is: does it have a function-field analog? does it have an analog for higher dimensional $A$? (I doubt that a similar statement can hold when $A$ is a product of lower dimensional things. So we should rule out this case?)

Comment: If $K$ is a global field of positive char $p$ and $A={\mathbb G}_{\text{m}}$, then $\text{ord}_v(P)$ always divides $p^e-1$ for some $e$, so the set ${\text{ord}_v(P): v\notin S}$ does not contain any power of $p$. Can the following weaker assertion hold: For any $p$-prime natural number $d$, the set ${\text{ord}_v(P): v\notin S}$  contains all but finitely many powers of $d$?